# How do I list 3 Div elements next to each other horizontally?

Tags: html, css, grid

I have 3 divs that contain essentially the same info. Each div is made up of an image/header/paragraph. Each tag (IMG/Header/Paragraph) in the div should be listed underneath of each other so that we see the image, title of the picture beneath the image, and some text about the image beneath the title. Each div just has a different class name, column1/column2/column3

Each div should be listed next to each other in a line going from left to right, but I can't seem to get this right. Can someone help?

[image]

```css
#portraitGrid {
  max-width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff99cc;
}

.column1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ff99cc;
}
```

```html
<div id="portraitGrid" class="column1">
    <img id="portfolioPortrait" class="portraitImage" src="Images/Humming 2.jpeg" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h3 id="portfolioPortrait" class="title">Humming Bird</h3>
    <p>
        The Humming Bird portrait was inspired by a card made for my boyfriend. The theme of this was to have make something romantic in a cute, simple, yet bold. Framed in a black shadow box, the color and designs stand out even stronger.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you use some frameworks like bootstrap? And should this be responsive?

Comment: Flexbox, or css-grid would be the best solution here. I personally would favor css-grid for such task. Float was never intended for stylign purpose. Its for floating images within a etxt paragraph only. many guides still mis-use the float property as this was mis-used commonly befor the introduction of flexbox and css-grid nearly 10 years ago. As Flexbox and css-grid is supported by everybrowser (with exeption of older IE, limited supprot for IE 11 and 13 for css-grid), there is no reason not to use the modern styling techniques.

Comment: PS: `<br>` is an empty tag. it does not need to be closed or a slash at the end. Also if you put it 2 times after each other, you do soemthing wrong. in that case you should simply add a `margin-bottom: 2em;` which will have the exact same effect by default without to hard-code it HTML wise. Same for the `<img>` tag. its also an empty tag and doesnt need to be closed or a slash at the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should wrap you "columns" into a div. In that case they will be called grid-card. Apply a grid system by using `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` on your container `#portaitGrid`. `repeat(3, 1fr) will devide the space into 3 columns with the exact same width.

To add a gap between the cards, you can use `grid-gap`.

In your picture, the title and the image are smaller then the text block. As such I gave them only a width of 80% (80% of the card width) and centered them.

As I already said in the comments, 2x 
 is a bad use. As such I removed the linebreaks and added a margin-bottom to the image instead.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#portraitGrid {
  display : grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  background-color: #ff99cc;
  padding: 15px;
}

#portraitGrid div img {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10% 1em 10%;
}

#portraitGrid div h3 {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

```html
<section id="portraitGrid">
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
    <h3>Hamster</h3>
    <p>My name is Yoshi. I'm a syrian hamster. My picture is often used for demonstration purpose at Stackoverflow by my owner.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0736.jpg">
    <h3>Food</h3>
    <p>I enjoy eating water-melons.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Areno/IMAG0845.jpg">
    <h3>Hobbies</h3>
    <p>My favorite hobby is sleeping during daytime
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked out. There are a few adjustments I will try to tweak/also have to review some of the tags and formats used as I'm very new to coding, but overall, this solved my question/issue to exactly how I needed. Thank you, again.

Comment: your welcome, if you specify the adjustments, i can help with that.

Comment: Hi again! Apologies  on the delay, I was sick the past few days and have not had a chance to respond. I would like the font to be perhaps a bit larger, and for the images on the far right and left to be a bit closer to the margin/edge.